# How to set timeout for "SELECT FOR UPDATE" in transaction in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, timeout, select-for-update

I have `product` table with `id`, `name` and `stock` as shown below.

#### `product` table:

| id | name | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 10 |
| 2 | Orange | 20 |

Then, after T1 runs `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, T2 needs to wait for T1 to commit for a long time to run `SELECT FOR UPDATE` as shown below because `SELECT FOR UPDATE` doesn't have timeout by default:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Step 1 | `BEGIN;` |  | T1 starts. |
| Step 2 |  | `BEGIN;` | T2 starts. |
| Step 3 | `SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2 FOR UPDATE;` 20 |  | With "SELECT FOR UPDATE", T1 reads `20`. |
| Step 4 |  | `SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2 FOR UPDATE;` | T2 needs to wait for T1 to commit to read `stock` with "SELECT FOR UPDATE". |
| Step 5 |  | Waiting... | ... |
| Step 6 |  | Waiting... | ... |
| Step ... |  | Waiting... | ... |
| Step ... |  | Waiting... | ... |
| Step ... |  | Waiting... | ... |
| Step 98 | `COMMIT;` | Waiting... | T1 commits. |
| Step 99 |  | `SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2 FOR UPDATE;` 20 | Now with "SELECT FOR UPDATE", T2 reads `20` |
| Step 100 |  | `COMMIT;` | T2 commits. |

Now, I want T2 to rollback 3 seconds after T2 waits for T1 as shown below:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Step 1 | `BEGIN;` |  | T1 starts. |
| Step 2 |  | `BEGIN;` | T2 starts. |
| Step 3 | `SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2 FOR UPDATE;` 20 |  | With "SELECT FOR UPDATE", T1 reads `20`. |
| Step 4 |  | `SELECT stock FROM product WHERE id = 2 FOR UPDATE;` | T2 needs to wait for T1 to commit to read `stock` with "SELECT FOR UPDATE". |
| Step 5 |  | Waiting... | ... |
| Step 6 |  | Waiting... | ... |
| Step 7 |  | ROLLBACK; | T2 rollbacks 3 seconds after T2 waits for T1. |
| Step ... |  |  |  |
| Step ... |  |  |  |
| Step 98 |  |  |  |
| Step 99 |  |  |  |
| Step 100 | `COMMIT;` |  | T1 commits. |

So, how can I set the timeout of 3 seconds for `SELECT FOR UPDATE` in transaction in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20963803/8963723

```sql
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL lock_timeout = '3s';
SELECT ....;
COMMIT;
```